# .NET Framework 2 compatible API to plot a graph

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I need a .NET Framework 2 compatible C# API or free library to plot some not typical curves by points. I'm not allowed to use .NET Framework 3 or higher. Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZedGraph : http://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-details/41/ZedGraph/ supports .NET 2.0. I have not used it, got curious about this and found it after searching. A word of caution though : Looking at the history of changes in sourceforge, it doesnt seem to be very actively maintained (Last update was in 2012), something that you may have to think about.